# Mysterious syntax error at SET in MySQL Stored Proc

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a simple table that has two columns: an auto-increment int column called id and a date column called start.  I'm trying to write a stored procedure that, given a value, will calculate the appropriate record to tie it to.  The problem is that I'm getting a syntax error that doesn't really tell me what's going on.  The error is:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET finalResult = candidate;

Here is the code I'm using to create the procedure.  Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE FindGCLDate(IN targetDate DATE)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE candidate DATE;
        DECLARE finalResult DATE;
        DECLARE loopComplete BOOLEAN;
        DECLARE allDates CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM gcl_dates;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
            SET loopComplete = TRUE;

        OPEN allDates;

        myLoop : LOOP
            FETCH allDates INTO candidate;
            SELECT candidate;
            IF targetDate < candidate
                SET finalResult = candidate;  -- this is the offending line
                SET loopComplete = TRUE;
            END IF;

            IF loopComplete THEN
                CLOSE allDates;
                LEAVE myLoop;
            END IF;
        END LOOP myLoop;

        SELECT finalResult;
    END //
```

I know there is more wrong with the procedure -- I haven't defined an out parameter or returned anything yet.  But I'm just wondering why I am getting this error.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to write a stored procedure to do that? Seems fairly simple to do the same using a single SELECT, unless I am misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `THEN` on the line above it:

```
IF targetDate < candidate
```

should be

```
IF targetDate < candidate THEN
```

From the [fine manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/if-statement.html), the syntax for an `IF` statement is this:

```
IF search_condition THEN statement_list
    [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END IF
```

where optional things are, as usual, marked with brackets; there are not brackets around `THEN` so it is required.

Comment: Ah ha, I thought it would be something simple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE FindGCLDate(IN targetDate DATE)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE candidate DATE;
        DECLARE finalResult DATE;
        DECLARE loopComplete BOOLEAN;
        DECLARE allDates CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM gcl_dates;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
            SET loopComplete = TRUE;

        OPEN allDates;

        myLoop : LOOP
            FETCH allDates INTO candidate;
            SELECT candidate;
            IF targetDate < candidate THEN   -- You had missed THEN
                SET finalResult = candidate;  -- this is the offending line
                SET loopComplete = TRUE;
            END IF;

            IF loopComplete THEN
                CLOSE allDates;
                LEAVE myLoop;
            END IF;
        END LOOP myLoop;

        SELECT finalResult;
    END //
```

You have missed THEN after IF statement :)